# Prevent JavaScript Timer Re-entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

My ASP.NET MVC page uses JavaScript/jQuery to poll my database every second.

This is working but I want to make sure that, if there is a delay, my timer handler won't get called again before it has returned.

In there any trick to this other than storing the timer ID in a global variable, clearing the timer in my handler, and restarting it when my handler is done.

**NOTE:** I realize every second seems frequent but this code is polling my server after submitting a credit card payment. Normally, it will only run for a second or so, and I don't want the user to wait any longer than necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polling every second? That's quite heavy!

That aside, you won't have this issue when [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) is used instead of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval). The latter ensures that a piece of code is run x times given a interval, while the former ensures that there's a delay of at least x milliseconds.

```
function some_poller() {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/some_page',
       success: function() {
           setTimeout(some_poller, 1000);
       },
       error: function() { // Also retry when the request fails
           setTimeout(some_poller, 1000);
       }
    });
}

// Init somewhere
some_poller();
```

Comment: I need to keep running that code until I get a result or I've waited too long. Am I correct that `setTimeout` only calls the target once and then clear any internal timer used by that function? In other words, I can use this, but I must call `setTimeout` again each time my handler is called?

Comment: @JonathanWood `setTimeout` doesn't clear anything, since it's supposed to run a function **once**. `setInterval`, on the other hand, ensures that a given function is periodically executed. Read the linked documentation if you're still confused.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, although I wouldn't recommend using a global variable.  Stick it inside some function.

But are you really sure you need to poll every second?  That's an extremely chatty interface.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience a "global", (inside of the root function), variable works very well in this instance so that you can control when to clear and restart. If the response is really as quick as you say, this shouldn't cause too much overhead, (clearing/resetting), and will allow to account for these type of situations.